# Redirect to Login for isFullyAuthenticated() URL and then, back again

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1.x and trying to achieve the following scenario:

- a page is secured with isFullyAuthenticated()
- the current user is only authenticated with Remember Me, so **not fully authenticated**
- the user navigates to this fully authenticated page - this should **not be permitted** (and it's not)
- however, the user should not get the 403 page - instead, the user should be prompted to login via the Login form
- after logging in, the user should be allowed to proceed to the page he previously requested, since now he's a fully authenticated user

My Spring Security config is:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/full_auth_only.html" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/authenticated.html" />
    <logout />
    <remember-me key="someAppKey" />

</http>
```

And I tried to add:

```
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/login.html" />
```

However, the problem is now that, when visiting the page, I am indeed prompted by the Login form, only the URL doesn't correspond to login; instead it's the URL of the fully authenticated page:

`http://localhost:8080/spring-security/admin/full_auth_only.html`

Which then breaks the authentication process, which fails when trying to access the (invalid) URL: 
`http://localhost:8080/spring-security/admin/j_spring_security_check`

This should have been: 
`http://localhost:8080/spring-security/j_spring_security_check`

Any help on this is appreciated - I think the usecase is very common and so I would prefer using the namespace support instead of going in a custom direction.

Thanks. 
Eugen.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue with version `3.1.3.RELEASE` of Spring Security. Which version do you use?

Authentication requests are intercepted by the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that checks if the URL of the request **ends with** a pre-configured value (that defaults to `/j_spring_security_check`). Any URL with that ending will trigger an authentication attempt. You can see the related code [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L245-248).

This means that the URL you said is invalid should in fact be processed without problems.

The code linked above hasn't been changed since very early versions (`2.x`), so there should be some other issues in your case.

If you could share your configuration and some debug level logs, that would help to reveal what's the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove any `welcome-file-list` if you have in `web.xml`.

2.Make sure `always-use-default-target` is **not set to** `false` in `form-login` tag or remove it all together.

3.And make sure you have permitted every one to access your login page. something like this `<intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll()"/>`

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the cookie was not set, and the following requests sent were all treated as the first requests without a session ID, so spring security asked for login every time even though you had logged in.

If you were using google chrome, and tested the application in your local machine using the localhost address, the cookie might not be set. And it is a known issue with Google chrome.

You can try 127.0.0.1 instead to test. Or try another web browser like Internet Explorer.